# SQL - Selecting last event for each user that matches a given criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I've prepared the following simplified example of my real case: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/19c9d/1/1).

As evident, I've come up with two ways to get to the same information, which is: **the set of latest events for each user given some additional constraints on event type**.

Both ways get me the information about `user` and time `occurred` of the latest event. However, I need to know the `id` and `type` of that event as well.

How would I go about getting that?

Ideally, I'd like the solution to work for any SQL database, not just PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, I would use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (username) e.*
from events e
where type > 0
order by username, "time" desc;
```

(This does not order by time for all users; that would require another subquery.)

For a more general solution, I would use `row_numbe()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by username order by "time" desc) as seqnum
      from events e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1
order by "time" desc
```